# OpenTripPlanner is not returning stops within a given radius

Tags: openstreetmap, opentripplanner

OTP 1.4.0 will return all of the stops in the GTFS feed but will not return nearby stops when provided with lat/lon and radius. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to resolve it?

```
http://{my-otp-server}/otp/routers/default/index/stops?&lat={double}&lon={-double}&radius=.25
    RETURNS []
http://{my-otp-server}/otp/routers/default/index/stops
    RETURNS 3078 ROWS
```

Comment: I think the main problem is that the documentation for this endpoint does not specify the units used in the radius parameter. I assumed it was miles (.25) and got nothing. I get 44 results when I use the same distance in feet (1320). But that doesn't mean it's feet; it could be meters or something else.  
http://dev.opentripplanner.org/apidoc/1.4.0/resource_IndexAPI.html#resource_IndexAPI_getStopsInRadius_GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out through trial and error and by comparing results with a different API that the units for *radius* are **meters**.

Comment: @scai OTP was developed in Oregon so I figured miles would be a safe bet (given that they don't specify units in the docs). I guess we'll have to convert miles from users into meters for the API until the USA converts to metric…